# HTMLUnit in Java - How to navigate to GridView pages

Tags: javascript, java, jsoup, htmlunit

I'm trying to create an application using java that will read the info from a webpage. In order to download the info from the elements that I want I used jsoup (excellent tool!) but I want to load the next page of the GridView used in the webpage.
The page is an .aspx page and the link of the 2nd page is like that:

```
 <a href="javascript:__doPostBack('GridView1','Page$2')" style="color:White;">2</a>
```

Below is the javascript function used:

```
    //<![CDATA[
    var theForm = document.forms['form1'];
    if (!theForm) {
        theForm = document.form1;
    }
    function __doPostBack(eventTarget, eventArgument) {
        if (!theForm.onsubmit || (theForm.onsubmit() != false)) {
            theForm.__EVENTTARGET.value = eventTarget;
            theForm.__EVENTARGUMENT.value = eventArgument;
            theForm.submit();
        }
    }
    //]]>
```

Currently, I am trying to do it using HTMLUnit but looks like is not working. Below is the code I am using:

```
 final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);
            HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.webpage.com/Main.aspx");          
            HtmlAnchor anchor = null;
            List<HtmlAnchor> anchors = page.getAnchors();
            for (int j = 0; j < anchors.size(); j++)
            {
                anchor = anchors.get(j);
                String sAnchor = anchor.asText();               
                String sAnchorxml = anchor.asXml();         
                if (sAnchor.equals("2"))
                {
                    HtmlPage page2 = anchor.click();
                    doc = Jsoup.parse(page2.asXml());
                    .....
```

When I read the page using the same code that I read the 1st page I get the following error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(Unknown Source)
at java.util.ArrayList.get(Unknown Source)
at test.advacus.com.MainProgram.main(MainProgram.java:148)
```

I assume that my error is in the `'Jsoup.parse()'` line. Just to clarify that once you click on the next page the url is not changing, only the info in the GridView, so I cannot parse using the new url.

Any additional help or any suggested tool instead of HTMLUnit that will cooperate with jsoup better would really help!
Thank you in advance!

Edited for Additional info:
Looks like is `click()` that is not working... I modified the code and the newPage body looks like it contains the same info as the 1st page:

```
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);       
HtmlPage page = webClient.getPage("http://www.qatarsale.com/EnMain.aspx");                  
HtmlAnchor anchor = page.getAnchorByText("2");              
HtmlPage newPage = anchor.click();      
HtmlElement el = newPage.getBody();
System.out.println(el.asText());
```

Comment: Can you post the page url? `__doPostBack` will probably trigger a request in the background which could be reproduced with jsoup.

Comment: Hello F.Klein.... http://qatarsale.com/EnMain.aspx is the url... doPostBack looks like passing the next page parameter to ASP.Net server.... but unfortunately I didn't manage find a new url for this

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Inspecting the anchors - as you already pointed out - `doPostBack` is called, so it is much simpler to invoke the javascript call instead of first grabbing the anchors and calling click on it.

**Example code**

```
java.util.logging.Logger.getLogger("com.gargoylesoftware").setLevel(java.util.logging.Level.OFF);
final WebClient webClient = new WebClient(BrowserVersion.CHROME);

webClient.getOptions().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnScriptError(false);
webClient.getOptions().setThrowExceptionOnFailingStatusCode(false);
webClient.getOptions().setTimeout(10000);

try {
    HtmlPage htmlPage = webClient.getPage("http://qatarsale.com/EnMain.aspx");

    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(htmlPage.asXml());

    System.out.println(doc.select("[id$=Label10]").text());

    ScriptResult result = htmlPage.executeJavaScript("__doPostBack('GridView1','Page$2')");
    htmlPage = (HtmlPage)result.getNewPage();

    Thread.sleep(3000); // delay needed for lazy loading, there might be something cleaner

    doc = Jsoup.parse(((HtmlPage)htmlPage).asXml());

    System.out.println(doc.select("[id$=Label10]").text());

} catch (Exception e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
} finally {
    webClient.close();
}
```

**Output**

```
Toyota Porsche Mercedes-Benz Cadillac Jeep Porsche Porsche Nissan Mitsubishi BMW Porsche Ford Mitsubishi Toyota Nissan Land Rover Nissan Mercedes-Benz Nissan Nissan Toyota Toyota Porsche Mitsubishi Mitsubishi Nissan Nissan Mercedes-Benz Nissan Jeep Mercedes-Benz Lexus BMW Lexus
BMW Lexus Toyota Toyota Lexus Nissan Mercedes-Benz Mercedes-Benz Ferrari Dodge BMW Mercedes-Benz Aston Martin Mitsubishi Suzuki Maserati Porsche Maserati Land Rover Chevrolet Land Rover GMC Toyota Porsche Lexus Land Rover GMC Mercedes-Benz Toyota Lexus Toyota Lexus Toyota Nissan
```